# Why do incomplete if statements create latches during synthesis in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, digital, flip-flop

Why is it when we try to synthesize incomplete if statements in VHDL the synthesizer uses latches instead of flip-flops?

An explanation from a digital/circuit standpoint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn) 6.2.1.1 Level-sensitive storage from process with sensitivity list "A level-sensitive storage element shall be modeled for a signal (or variable) when all the following apply: a) The signal (or variable) has an explicit assignment. b) The signal (or variable) does not have an execution path with <clock_edge> as a condition. c) There are executions of the process that do not execute an explicit assignment (via an assignment statement) to the signal (or variable)." Identity assignments are ignored. Note the lack of a clock edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: because the behaviour of a latch matches that of an incomplete IF. A register does not.

```
if (A)
   B = C;
```

If the condition A is true and C changes, the output B follows the input immediately. If A is false B keeps it value. This behavior of the IF statement corresponds with the behavior of a latch. Thus a latch is what is generated.

You can not generate this behaviour with a register.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of the question is wrong. The latch is not inferred instead of a flip-flop.

Flip-flops are inferred every time a signal goes through a clocked process even with an incomplete IF statement. For example, the following code infers a flip-flop:

```
process(clock) is
begin
   if rising_edge(clock) then
      if (A) then
         B <= C;
      end if;
   end if;
end process;
```

Latches are inferred only in combinatorial logic processes when there is an incomplete IF statement. This is due to the fact that an incomplete if statement requires the storage of information which is not possible with the simpler elements of combinatorial logic (wires and gates).

Comment: Registers (and other logic) are inferred (not instantiated) from RTL code. Instantiation is when you directly instantiate another entity. `inst : entity work.dff port map (clk => clk, d=> d, q => q);` etc

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't answer to [oldfart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3535598/oldfart) (not enough reputation), so technically the short answer is kinda correct.

But, the long answer has different variables: what kind of design do you implement, what tool do you use and what platform is your target.

E.g. Quartus II 16.1, Cyclone V CSXFC6D6F31C6 such code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity d_latch_test is
port 
(
    signal clk      : in std_logic;
    enable  : in std_logic;
    sr_in       : in std_logic;
    sr_out  : out std_logic
);

end entity;

architecture rtl of d_latch_test is

begin

process (clk)
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (enable = '1') then
            sr_out <= sr_in;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end rtl;
```

Quartus Synthesis would not tell you that your code is a latch, but it is a D-flip-flop 
[image: Quartus RTL Viewer]

But! It has asynchronous input.

So basically you can do a flip-flop from if-statement.